# How do I detect irregular borders in an image?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic

Given the image below, what algorithm might I use to detect whether regions one and two (identified by color) have a border?

http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/4477/borders.png

If there's a C# example out there, that would be awesome, but I'm really just looking for any example code.

**Edit:** Using Jaro's advice, I came up with the following...

```
public class Shape
{
    private const int MAX_BORDER_DISTANCE = 15;

    public List<Point> Pixels { get; set; }

    public Shape()
    {
        Pixels = new List<Point>();
    }

    public bool SharesBorder(Shape other)
    {
        var shape1 = this;
        var shape2 = other;

        foreach (var pixel1 in shape1.Pixels)
        {
            foreach (var pixel2 in shape2.Pixels)
            {
                var xDistance = Math.Abs(pixel1.X - pixel2.X);
                var yDistance = Math.Abs(pixel1.Y - pixel2.Y);

                if (xDistance > 1 && yDistance > 1)
                {
                    if (xDistance * yDistance < MAX_BORDER_DISTANCE)
                        return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (xDistance < Math.Sqrt(MAX_BORDER_DISTANCE) &&
                        yDistance < Math.Sqrt(MAX_BORDER_DISTANCE))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Clicking on two shapes that do share a border returns fairly quickly, but very distance shapes or shapes with a large number of pixels take 3+ seconds at times. What options do I have for optimizing this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what the constraints are on a solution. In your edited code you are storing the shapes as a list of pixels. Can these be ordered in any way? Can we represent the shapes in a 2 dimensional array with an offset? If we can do stuff like that then the solution to the problem becomes faster.

Comment: The distance between 2 points is `distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x1-x2), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(y1-y2), 2))`.
Also when you find 2 region points it is probable that the border is somewhere between them (not certain). So you can check pixels using the vector till you reach a border (or fail).

Comment: That's an O(n^2) algorithm, which will get really slow when your shapes are any significant size. Also, sqrt is a slow operation. Generally it's faster to square your distance too, and compared the squared values.

Comment: True, but if you actually want the exact distance to optimise vector approach for the points, you have no choice (or you can use absolute value).
Optimistically you would only need to really check their distance once or twice per shape.

Comment: Right, but he doesn't need to know the exact distance, he only needs to know that the distance is less than N. Or, in other words, he only needs to know that the distance squared is less than N squared.

Comment: @Jaro, you're right, I should check for an actual border once I've determined a valid distance. I'll add that later. For now I'm just trying to optimize the proximity check. @Sean, in my modified code, I'm squaring the distance and checking that first, but in the case where either X or Y distance is 0, I have to check if the non-zero value is less than the square root of the max distance, yes? Maybe I'm missing something there...

Comment: I think the next optimization is to subdivide each shape and test those before testing on a per-pixel basis. I'm not sure how best to do that off the top of my head, so I'll be experimenting there, possibly using the quadtree info linked by Sean.

Comment: Well then. Using a vector between two region points will help us approximate the probable border (if it does exist).
This would IMHO have good results:
a) Find red point `r`
b) Find green point `g`
c) Check around those point perpendicular to the vector so we know they are not too close to borders.
d) Move points `g` and `r` closer along the vector - either you reach black pixels only or not in which case you would repeat the procedure moving the point perpendicular to the current vector.

Comment: OK yeah, I'm really not getting this.

Comment: Why not make a path following one of te regions inner border?

Comment: @Chris: Let's have 2 points `R` and `G` in 2 different regions. Draw a line between them (an abscissa), you get a positional vector (like direction from point `R` to `G`). For provided case, there is a high chance, that the border between those 2 regions lies on this abscissa. So move the `R` and `B` closer together (along the abscissa using the vector) until you reach border (B). Graphical explanation (kind of ;)):
R----B----G -> -R---B---G- -> ... -> ----RBG----

Comment: @belisarius: that could be the next step after you find the abscissa between the regions (as a hint of their relative position). You could also find all (with certain precision) bordering points of 1 region and project directional vectors outwards. That would definitely detect border with another region. I would try the abscissa first though as there is a very good chance you will find the border on the first try - if it exists. Of course, both examples expect that the Bitmap has been scanned with some precision to actually get some red or green points to start with.

Comment: Check the code I have posted in my answer. That should describe (the first step) of what I was describing in my comments. My code has found all the borders on your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 regions having border means that within a certain small area there should be 3 colors present: red, black and green.

So a very ineffective solution presents itself:
using `Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);` you could scan an area for those 3 colors. The area must be larger than the width of the border of course.

There is of course plenty room for optimizations (like going in 50 pixels steps and decreasing the precision continually).
Since black is the least used color, you would search around black areas first.

This should explain what I have written in various comments in this topic:

```
namespace Phobos.Graphics
{
    public class BorderDetector
    {
        private Color region1Color = Color.FromArgb(222, 22, 46);
        private Color region2Color = Color.FromArgb(11, 189, 63);
        private Color borderColor = Color.FromArgb(11, 189, 63);

        private List<Point> region1Points = new List<Point>();
        private List<Point> region2Points = new List<Point>();
        private List<Point> borderPoints = new List<Point>();

        private Bitmap b;

        private const int precision = 10;
        private const int distanceTreshold = 25;

        public long Miliseconds1 { get; set; }
        public long Miliseconds2 { get; set; }

        public BorderDetector(Bitmap b)
        {
            if (b == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("b");

            this.b = b;
        }

        private void ScanBitmap()
        {
            Color c;

            for (int x = precision; x < this.b.Width; x += BorderDetector.precision)
            {
                for (int y = precision; y < this.b.Height; y += BorderDetector.precision)
                {
                    c = this.b.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (c == region1Color) region1Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    else if (c == region2Color) region2Points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    else if (c == borderColor) borderPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Returns a distance of two points (inaccurate but very fast).</summary>
        private int GetDistance(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            return Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) + Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y);
        }

        /// <summary>Finds the closests 2 points among the points in the 2 sets.</summary>
        private int FindClosestPoints(List<Point> r1Points, List<Point> r2Points, out Point foundR1, out Point foundR2)
        {
            int minDistance = Int32.MaxValue;
            int distance = 0;

            foundR1 = Point.Empty;
            foundR2 = Point.Empty;

            foreach (Point r1 in r1Points)
                foreach (Point r2 in r2Points)
                {
                    distance = this.GetDistance(r1, r2);

                    if (distance < minDistance)
                    {
                        foundR1 = r1;
                        foundR2 = r2;
                        minDistance = distance;
                    }
                }

            return minDistance;
        }

        public bool FindBorder()
        {
            Point r1;
            Point r2;

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

            watch.Start();
            this.ScanBitmap();
            watch.Stop();
            this.Miliseconds1 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            watch.Start();
            int distance = this.FindClosestPoints(this.region1Points, this.region2Points, out r1, out r2);
            watch.Stop();
            this.Miliseconds2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            this.b.SetPixel(r1.X, r1.Y, Color.Green);
            this.b.SetPixel(r2.X, r2.Y, Color.Red);

            return (distance <= BorderDetector.distanceTreshold);
        }
    }
}
```

It is very simple. Searching this way only takes about **2 + 4 ms** (scanning and finding the closest points).

You could also do the search recursively: first with precision = 1000, then precision = 100 and finally precision = 10 for large images.
FindClosestPoints will practically give you an estimated rectangual area where the border should be situated (usually borders are like that).

Then you could use the vector approach I have described in other comments.

Comment: Assuming the shapes are all the same color and I have an array of pixels that makes up each shape, I could also test for proximity between pixels from each shape, yeah? Is there an efficient way to do this besides looping through each pixel in one shape and testing for proximity to every pixel in the other shape?

Comment: Each region must be of **different color**, otherwise a **floodfill** algorithm would have to be run first for the method to work (which would also make the method not so effective) and a vector approach would be more useful.

Comment: Another performance improvement could be achieved by using a simple `X, Y struct` instead of the class `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as asking whether the two points exist in different regions. Is this correct? If so, I would probably use a variation of [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). It's not super difficult to implement (don't implement it recursively, you will almost certainly run out of stack space) and it will be able to look at complex situations like a U-shaped region that has a border *between* two points, but are not actually different regions. Basically run flood fill, and return true when your coordinate matches the target coordinate (or perhaps when it's close enough for your satisfaction, depending on your use case)

[Edit] Here is [an example](http://dev.largerussiangames.com/repositories/entry/sharplike/Sharplike/trunk/Tools/Sharplike.Editlike/MapTools/FloodTool.cs) of flood fill that I wrote for a project of mine. The project is CPAL-licensed, but the implementation is pretty specific to what I use it for anyway, so don't worry about copying parts of it. And it doesn't use recursion, so it should be able to scale to pixel data.

[Edit2] I misunderstood the task. I don't have any example code that does exactly what you're looking for, but I can say that comparing pixel-per-pixel the entire two regions is not something you want to do. You can reduce the complexity by partitioning each region into a larger grid (maybe 25x25 pixels), and comparing those sectors first, and if any of those are close enough, do a pixel-per-pixel comparison just within those two sectors.

[Edit2.5] [Quadtree][3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) might be able to help you too. I don't have a lot of experience with it, but I know it's popular in 2D collision detection, which is similar to what you're doing here. Might be worth researching.

Comment: I'm actually already using a modified flood fill algorithm to collect the pixels in each shape. The task now is to identify if any of the pixels in shape 2 are within N distance of any of the pixels in shape 1, where N is the approximate width of the border.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're determining adjacency of the two regions. Hang on, I will edit.

Comment: If you're collecting all the pixels in the shapes, and the shapes will look something like your example, then making note of the bounding boxes of the shapes will make life easier.

Comment: Bounding boxes would certainly make a good initial broadphase, but in the example he posted, most of the bounding boxes will overlap, so in practice it's not gonna do much. You'd still have an O(n^2) comparison on pixels unless you subdivide deeper, ruling out early any pixels that can't possibly be close enough.

Comment: Cool, that is exactly what I am suggesting, didn't know there is a term for it - Quadtree.

Comment: I don't think that 'most' of the bounding boxes will overlap (even when extended by a few pixels to account for the border). And in the cases that they don't, your speed improvement is huge. And if the pixels were stored in a 2d array the size of the bounding box then you could limit the search to the overlapping pixels. That beig said, absolute agreement about the need to avoid the naive brute force approach with the pixels.

Comment: I was able to cut the time down with a combination of the faster but less accurate distance measurement and a while loop that starts with a high precision value (say, 1000) and loops, dividing the precision by 2 each time until candidate pixels are found or the precision reaches 1.  Thanks for your help!